# Proxy an array in Java

Tags: java, proxy

For debugging purposes I want to create a proxy for an array `Object[]` but I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

when casting the proxy to `Object[]`. I am using the `DebugProxy` code from the Oracle tutorial: [dynamic proxy tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html). Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] obArr = new Object[10];
    Object proxy = DebugProxy.newInstance(obArr);
    obArr = (Object[]) proxy;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obArr));
}
```

Is there a way to create a proxy for an array?

Comment: Can you post an extract of your code?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin, updated.

Comment: I think the error stands in this statement, `Object proxy = DebugProxy.newInstance(obArr);`. If you are creating a proxy to `Object[]`, why are you trying to assign it to an `Object`?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin, well, skipping the local variable and inlining the assignment to `Object[]` yields the same result.